# What is typical webgl MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE in 2023?

Tags: gpu, webgl

I understand that `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` is GPU-dependent. Is there any information about what GPU's support various max texture sizes?

Alternatively, are they any browser usage statistics that report things like `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`?

In particular, I am looking to find how typical it is in 2023 for a device to support *at least* `8,192` as a `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` beyond anecdotal reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [OpenGL Hardware Database](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org) with ~11,000 entries, the [typical value for MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displaycapability.php?name=GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE) as of December 2023 is 16384 (~73%), followed by 32768 (~17.5%) and 8192 (~7.5%). So in total ~98% support a MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE of at least 8192.

Strictly speaking, this value is driver-specific, so you *might* get different values on the same GPU but with a different driver. However, the OpenGL Hardware DB considers this.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about this database, but it is exactly what I was looking for!